# Symfony FOSUserbundle - Best practice for setting role on account creation (with db query)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, fosuserbundle

When registering, I want to check another table if their username exists, and if it does, set another role for that user.

Would I do this in the user event constructor, a listener, the registration controller? I tried a couple of these but had issues actually accessing the entity manager to query the table

So what I'm wanting to run (somewhere) when a user is being registered (or confirming their email)

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $uniID = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $user->getUsername());

    if ($em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->userHasMembership($uniID) == 1) {
        $user->addRole('ROLE_MEMBER');
    } else {
        $user->removeRole('ROLE_MEMBER');
    }

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

For now I've injected the entity manager into my service

```
app.registration_completed:
    class: UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
    arguments:
         - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

And my event listener is the following

class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

```
protected $em;
function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
    );
}

public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $uniID = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $user->getUsername());

    if ($this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->userHasMembership($uniID) == 1) {
        $roles = array('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_MEMBER');
    } else {
        $roles = array('ROLE_USER');
    }
    $user->setRoles($roles);
}
```

Comment: I'd probably do it in the registration controller (unless there are other places where users can register?). What kind of trouble were you having with the EntityManager?

Comment: like in this example? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

You have posted errors occurred in question. I recommend you to always share error with code you have tried so others would be conformable to solve the issue.

Please try below.
Simply pass `doctrine` object argument in services and set entity manager in `__construct()`.

**services.yml**

```
app.registration_completed:
    class: UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
    arguments:
         - "@doctrine"
```

**RegistrationConfirmListener.php**

```
class RegistrationConfirmListener implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    protected $em;

    function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine) // Get doctrine argument
    {
        $this->em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $uniID = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $user->getUsername());

        if ($this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->userHasMembership($uniID) == 1) {
            $roles = array('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_MEMBER');
        } else {
            $roles = array('ROLE_USER');
        }
        $user->setRoles($roles);
    }
}
```

It's working fine in Symfony 2.3